# Divide text by set number of words

Tags: r, text-mining

I have title(column 1), text(column 2) matrix.

the text cell's string length is more than 10,000 words. (but few cell's are not.)

I want to divide the text cells by 2,000 words with same title.
(so that the original matrix[1,1] will be more than five column with same title name and less than 2,000 words of characters)

I goggled and found codes about it(maybe;;) but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

```
makeflextextchunks <- function(doc.object, chunk.size=2000, percentage=TRUE){
  paras <- getNodeset(doc.object, "/d:TEI/d:text/d:body/d:p",
                      c(d="http://www.tel-c.org/ns/1.0"))
  words <- paste(sapply(paras.xmlvalue), collapse= " ")
  words.lower <- tolower(words)
  words.l <- strsplit(words.lower, "\\s+")
  word.v <- unlis(words.l)
  x <- seq_along(word.v)
  if(percentage){
    max.length <- length(word.v)/chunk.size
    chunks.l <- split (word.v, ceiling(x/max.length))
  }else{
    chunks.l <- split(word.v, ceiling(x/chunk.size))
    if(length(chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)]]) <-
       length(chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)]])/2)(
         chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)-1]] <-
           c(chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)-1]],
             chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)]])
         chunks.l[[length(chunks.l)]] <- NULL
  }
}
chunks.l <- lappy(chunks.l, paste, collaplse= " ")
chunks.df <- do.call(rbind, chunks.l)
return(chunk.sdf)
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question a `small reproduciable example`. And mention your final goal *clearly*.

Comment: This approach will produce a ragged matrix (i.e. some rows with have NAs in the latter columns.) This is usually ill-advised as you will now have to handle the NA's and your data will not look "aligned"